# Simplify function with condition not working

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

I try to simplify the function Q below:

```
Q[x_] := Sign[x] /; x > 1
Simplify[Q[x], Assumptions -> x > 1]
(*return Q[x]*)
```

But it doesn't work. However, if I write something like this:

```
Q[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sign[x], x > 1}}]
Simplify[Q[x], Assumptions -> x > 1]
(*return 1*)
```

It works well. Why is this curious difference? I have searched the documentation but found no help. And is there a third way to write the function Q? I found the double curly braces rather ugly.

Comment: Because when you call `Q[x]`, there is no value yet for `x`. So it returns back `Q[x]` as is. And simplify just sees `Q[x]` if you replace it with `Simplify[Sign[x], Assumptions -> x > 1]` then it works because Simplify now see `Sign[x]` in front of it.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you for your comment. That's really helpful. But I still want to know if there is a way to let `Simplify` know what's inside. `Piecewise` is not what I want, partly because the braces are ugly and partly because it always has a default value.

Comment: Well, if you change the definition, then it works `Q[x_] := Sign[x];
Simplify[Q[x], Assumptions -> x > 1]`  because now the call to `Q[x]` goes through since it is symbolic. When you write `Q[x_/;x>1] := Sign[x]` then only when `x>1` will the call go through which is not the case.

Comment: Try `Q[x_] := Sign[x] /; Simplify[x > 1];
Assuming[x > 1, Simplify[Q[x]]]` per the preceding linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before feeding a function to "Simplify" it will be evaluated. Now, consider:

```
Clear[Q];
Q[x_] := Sign[x] /; x > 1
Q[x]
(*Q[x]*)

Clear[Q]
Q[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sign[x], x > 1}}]
Q[x]
```

[image]

As you see, the difference is that in the first stage of evaluation Q[x] is not replaced in the first case and replace in the second case.

If you ensure that Q[x] is always replaced it will do what you want. This can be achieved by using "Set" instead of "SetDelayed":

```
Clear[Q]
Q[x_] = Sign[x] /; x > 1;
Q[x]
Simplify[Q[x], Assumptions -> x > 1]
```

[image]